# Wordpress: Flag comment for moderation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a Wordpress plugin that will allow my users to flag, or rate a comment for moderation.

Essentially, if a number of people flag a comment, it is added to the moderation queue.

I have found a few plugins but none seem to work with any recent versions of WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/safe-report-comments/

```
Requires: 3.3 or higher
Compatible up to: 3.4.2
Last Updated: 2012-11-8
Downloads: 2,365
```